# if elseif statement cause input field force to use option value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

First of all, my select option is working but my input field is not working when I submit. I'm using if else if statement to query my database based on the option.

I suspect this part elseif not working:

```
elseif ($option == "") {
    $start_date = $_POST['start'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end'];
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start_date);
    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end_date);
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= :start AND log_datetime < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY;");
    $success = $query->execute(array(':start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'), ':end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d')));
} else {
    echo "No Data Input";
}
```

But for sure my query definately work because I tested in a separate file, but when I combine both option and input, the input couldn't work and it automatic go to `today` option whch is the first `if statement`.

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <select name="report">
    <option id="">Select Report Time</option>
    <option id="today">Today</option>
    <option id="yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option id="thisweek">This Week</option>
    <option id="thismonth">This Month</option>
    <option id="thisyear">This Year</option>
    <option id="lastweek">Last Week</option>
    <option id="lastmonth">Last Month</option>
    <option id="lastyear">Last Year</option>
</select><br />
From: <input type="text" name="start" /><br />
End: <input type="text" name="end" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And here is my all result.php php code excluding foreach :

```
if(empty($_POST['option']) && empty($_POST['start']) && empty($_POST['end'])) {
   echo 'Please don'."'".'t try to hack!<br /><a href="./" title="Retry">Click here to <b>retry</b> again</a>';
   exit;
}
$option = $_POST['report'];

if($option == "Today") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE();");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y');
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y');
} elseif ($option == "Yesterday") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND log_datetime < CURDATE();");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("-1 days"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("-1 days"));
} elseif ($option == "This Week") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) + 0 DAY);");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y');
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("+6 days"));
} elseif ($option == "This Month") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY);");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("first day of this month"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("last day of this month"));
} elseif ($option == "This Year") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE YEAR(log_datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE());");
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("first day of this month"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("last day of this year"));
    $success = $query->execute();
} elseif ($option == "Last Week") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND log_datetime < CURDATE();");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("-7 days"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("-1 days"));
} elseif ($option == "Last Month") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE YEAR(log_datetime) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(log_datetime) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("first day of last month"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("last day of last month"));
} elseif ($option == "Last Year") {
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE YEAR(log_datetime) = YEAR(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR);");
    $success = $query->execute();
    $startreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("first day of last year"));
    $endreportdate = date('d - M - Y', strtotime("last day of last year"));
} elseif ($option == "") {
    $start_date = $_POST['start'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end'];
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start_date);
    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end_date);
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= :start AND log_datetime < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY;");
    $success = $query->execute(array(':start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'), ':end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d')));
} else {
    echo "No Data Input";
}

$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

May I know where did I go wrong? Sorry for my messy code, I'm still learning and I'm using SO and php manual as reference, but for this problem I search Google and SO high and low and yet I couldn't find the exact question that can help me and I have to ask the question.

Appreciate to everyone who help and take your time to read this question.
Thank you.

Comment: @meda as I said, I'm still learning, I take my effort to study php manual and SO question. Sorry to say, but I'm still a beginner in programing.

Comment: Does it always goes to Today even if you havent selected an option?

Comment: if I didn't select any option it will exit the script because I put this on top `if(empty($_POST['option']) && empty($_POST['start']) && empty($_POST['end'])) {
   echo 'Please don'."'".'t try to hack!<br /><a href="./" title="Retry">Click here to <b>retry</b> again</a>';
   exit;
}` if I remove out this line, it still return me to the first option which is `today` option

Comment: thats because you use `empty()` instead of `isset()`

Comment: I believe not that part, because I change it from `empty()` to `isset()` it still return me "No Data Input" and `Notice: Undefined variable: query in result.php on line 78` which is this code `$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);` meaning to say, I suspect the code as I posted in first post the `elseif ($option == "") {
    $start_date = $_POST['start'];` part not working.

Comment: A backslash is all you need to escape that single quote. `echo 'Please don\'t try to hack!';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is caused by the fact that there is no `$_POST['option']` in your request you should check for `$_POST['report']` instead.

Now I'd suggest some improvements.

**First of all** change markup for select control in your html form by:

- introducing a `value` attribute for options
- adding a new option `Custom` to make it more obvious for user that he or she needs to choose your his or her own dates

That being said it might look like

```html
<select name='report'>
    <option value=''>Select Report Time</option>
    <option value='today'>Today</option>
    <option value='yesterday'>Yesterday</option>
    <option value='thisweek'>This Week</option>
    <option value='lastweek'>Last Week</option>
    <option value='thismonth'>This Month</option>
    <option value='lastmonth'>Last Month</option>
    <option value='thisyear'>This Year</option>
    <option value='lastyear'>Last Year</option>
    <option value='custom'>Custom</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE2: Secondly** you can check for request parameters and produce start and date in a following consistent way.

```sql
$periods = array(
    'today'     => array('start' => 'now', 'end' => 'now'),
    'yesterday' => array('start' => 'yesterday', 'end' => 'yesterday'),
    'thisweek'  => array('start' => 'monday this week', 'end' => 'sunday this week'),
    'lastweek'  => array('start' => 'monday last week', 'end' => 'sunday last week'),
    'thismonth' => array('start' => 'first day of this month', 'end' => 'last day of this month'),
    'lastmonth' => array('start' => 'first day of last month', 'end' => 'last day of last month'),
    'thisyear'  => array('start' => 'first day of january this year', 'end' => 'last day of december this year'),
    'lastyear'  => array('start' => 'first day of january last year', 'end' => 'last day of december last year')
);

if (isset($_POST['report']) && $_POST['report']) {
    $period = $_POST['report'];
    switch ($period) {
        case 'today':
        case 'yesterday':
        case 'thisweek':
        case 'lastweek':
        case 'thismonth':
        case 'lastmonth':
        case 'thisyear':
        case 'lastyear':
            $start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($periods[$period]['start']));
            $end   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($periods[$period]['end']));
            break;
        case 'custom':
            if (isset($_POST['start']) && $_POST['start'] &&
                isset($_POST['end']) && $_POST['end']) {
                $dt_start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['start']);
                $dt_end   = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $_POST['end']);
                if ($dt_start > $dt_end) {
                    echo 'Start date should be less than end date.';
                    exit;
                }
                $start = $dt_start->format('Y-m-d');
                $end   = $dt_end->format('Y-m-d');
            } else {
                echo 'Enter dates for report period.';
                exit;
            }
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Invalid report period.';
            exit;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Report period has not been selected';
    exit;
}
```

**Thirdly** PDO part stays **absolutely the same** and you use it only once

```sql
// assumption is that $db is properly instantiated
$sql = "SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= :start AND log_datetime < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array(':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end));
$rows = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

---

You can also build your conditions in SQL

```sql
-- today
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE()
   AND log_datetime <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
-- yesterday
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
   AND log_datetime <  CURDATE();
-- this week
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) DAY
   AND log_datetime <  CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) + 1 DAY;
-- this month
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
   AND log_datetime <  LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
-- this year
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY
   AND log_datetime <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
-- last year
SELECT *
  FROM log 
 WHERE log_datetime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
   AND log_datetime <  CURDATE() - INTERVAL DAYOFYEAR(CURDATE()) - 1 DAY;
```

Here is **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d22b/16)** demo

You can even wrap it in a stored procedure with an input parameter that tells what kind of period you need to fetch your data for.

---

Now **what you don't want to do** is to apply any functions (like this `YEAR(log_datetime)`) to columns in `WHERE` clause. By doing this you **prevent** MySQL from using an index(indices) on that column and effectively causing a **full scan**.

Comment: hey man! It's you again, thanks again for helping. I edited your post as the `$dt` variables seems to be wrong. Now I have a problem with the `custom` option. Whenever I select the date eg `1-1-2014` to `1-1-2014` or `5-1-2014` it throws me an error **`Select correct report period.`** and then I noticed you use switch case, so I use echo `$start` and `$end` for my report period, I use `echo $end = date('d - M - Y');` as I want to change the format of display, but it show me `today` date instead of the correct one.

Comment: You're welcome :). I updated that part of code. See updated answer. In your previous question the expected format for input was **`d/m/Y`** instead of `d-m-Y` that's why I used it. Anyway I changed it to `d-m-Y` now and of course you can tweak it and adjust it as you like.

Comment: thank you again, however there are three things that I have error. **first**: `'lastyear'  => array('start' => 'first day of last year', 'end' => 'last day of last year')` this part not working, it start from the `1-1-2013` and end on 31-1-2013` instead of `31-12-2013` **second**: I got no idea why this `if ($dt_start < $dt_end)` not working, it keep showing error message of `Start date should be less than end date.` but I change the value from **`<`** to **`>**` and it works.

Comment: **third** currently I'm using `if(isset($_POST['option']) && isset($_POST['start']) && isset($_POST['end'])) {
   echo 'Please don\'t try to hack!<br /><a href="./" title="Retry">Click here to <b>retry</b> again</a>';
   exit;
}` to make sure there are value before proceed to **result.php** but if I try use direct link, it will show undefined variable. Is there any way to **exit()** the script if people using direct link? `http://localhost/result.php`

Comment: I found a bug of `year` term at here **[year bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53650)** please advise, what will be alternative solution for the year report

Comment: 1) (year): changed relative date formats for this and last year. 2) it's a typo; of course it should be `if ($dt_start > $dt_end)`. There're also typos below `$dt-format()` changed to `$dt_start->format()` and `dt_end->format()` respectively 3) You can do checks exactly as I've done it. It won't proceed if the the script directly called. I changed the error messages and added additional `else` for clarity.

Comment: thanks now every part working except for proceed the script directly. I try use direct link and it show `Notice: Undefined variable: start in C:\xampp\htdocs\jeff\test\result.php on line 69` I notice you added `exit()` on no entry given, but it doesn't work on direct link. The line 69 is `$query->execute(array(':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end));`

Comment: do you mind taking a look at my other question on **[suggestion for creating database structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957748/suggestion-for-creating-mysql-database-structure)**? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change you condition:

```
if(isset($_POST['option']) && empty($_POST['start']) && empty($_POST['end'])) {
   echo 'Please don\'t try to hack!<br /><a href="./" title="Retry">Click here to <b>retry</b> again</a>';
   exit;
}
```

Finally compare to `Select Report Time` instead of `""`

```
elseif ($option == "Select Report Time") {
    $start_date = $_POST['start'];
    $end_date = $_POST['end'];
    $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $start_date);
    $end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $end_date);
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM log WHERE log_datetime >= :start AND log_datetime < :end + INTERVAL 1 DAY;");
    $success = $query->execute(array(':start'=>$start->format('Y-m-d'), ':end'=>$end->format('Y-m-d')));
}
```