# suggestion for creating mysql database structure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I'm currently working on building custom application. My first module already completed and now I'm still figuring out how to create the structure for second and third module to work flawlessly without any error or worst crash the whole database.

Some of the info:-

My first module, data are manually exported as the database is the main structure for my second and third module to work with.

My second module data are logs for report, where the data automatically enter to the database upon button submit click, (something like autosave, I assumed) This module will work as my report listing as in number customer visit of the week, top customer and etc.

Report outcome for visit of the day:

```
Customer Name | Date of Birth | Visit Count | Amount
   John Doe   |  1948-01-29   |       1     |   10
 Guest Guest  |  1968-12-16   |       1     |   10
```

My third module will be profile search where the data also automatically enter into the database upon button submit click. This module will work for the user to search the profile and proceed to the first module as well for the report usage listing as above behavior.

My current structure for **`log`**

- log_id (A.I)
- dob
- log_datetime
- log_count
- amount

And structure for **`profile`**

- profile_id (A.I)
- dob
- rowone
- rowtwo
- rowthree
- first_name
- last_name

Now I'll need to get the `profile` to attached to `log` when I use my second module for reporting whereby the report will show the detail from `log` table: `dob`, `log_datetime`, `log_count`, `amount` and `profile` table: `first_name`, `last_name`

If I add `profile_log_id` to `log` table and get `lastinsertID`, there is a problem that the user may not input the `first_name` or `last_name`: therefore I'll use `Guest` for `first_name` and `last_name` columm.

Also, I'll use `On Duplicate` to update the table if the details are the same, e.g. if the `first_name`, `last_name` and `dob` combination already exist, it will update the existing `profile` table.

So what is the way for me to get a better database design structure to ensure that the data are not conflict with each other and I still can make the report and profile search module work flawlessly?

Sorry for my long and complicated question, as this is my first application building and lack of experience in database design. Appreciate for everyone who help me to suggest and advise the better structure.

**Additional note:**

1. The first module which calculates the dob are stored a table with column of `dob_id`, `dob`, `rowone`, `rowtwo` and `rowthree` I couldn't explain more about this as this module is write based on my mom daily usage. All the data are manually entered to database to act as the main data pull over.
2. The second module is the `log` which record the daily log for reporting purpose. The column `dob` represent for daily customer `dob` while the `log_count` represent the **visit time** and `amount` represent the **amount** they pay for each visit.
3. The third module is the `profile` the user opted to fill in the customer name or not during the `dob` search from the first module which is a form for the user to enter the date, month and year (required field) and first name with last name as optional. As the query and insert are made separately, therefore the main data extract the data first and the end of the script will be the insert where the data extracted from main table (`dob`, `rowone`, `rowtwo`, `rowthree`) are enter into the profile table and log table (only `dob`). The `log_count` and `amount` are set so it will return the value to the database each time of insert.
4. Because of the first and last name is an optinal value, therefore I'll replace an empty of first and last name to `Guest` Guest` for recording purposes.
5. I need a search bar where the user can directly search the `profile` table for the first and last name and list out all the data of `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob`, `rowone`, `rowtwo`, `rowthree` that match the search criteria. This is use for regular customer only, to ease the search by recording their profile instead of keep asking for their `dob` everytime they visit and search by dob. That's why I'll use update the existing record instead of keep on insert the same data if `dob` `first_name` and `last_name` is match to avoid profile search showing duplicate data.

---

Live case scenario.

**For the month of January:** There are total of 20 customers visit.

- 4 customers visit are recorded and as the same person (John Doe - DOB: 1948-12-19).
- 3 customers visit are recorded and **it is different person as previous 4 visit** (John Doe - DOB: 2000-07-31)
- 5 customers visit are recorded as the same person (Vin Diesel - DOB: 1959-03-22)
- 5 customers visit are recorded as the same person (Teresa John - DOB: 1988-05-18)
- 1 customers visit are recorded (Guest Guest - DOB: 1977-11-17)
- 1 customers visit are recorded (Guest Guest - DOB: 1962-09-28)
- 1 customers visit are recorded (Guest Guest - DOB: 1977-11-17)

Guest Guest are not allowed to combine the visit:

The report outcome which join the table of `log`and `profile`

```
Customer Name | Date of Birth | Visit Count | Amount
   John Doe   |  1948-12-19   |       4     |   40
   John Doe   |  2000-07-31   |       3     |   30
  Vin Diesel  |  1959-03-22   |       5     |   50
 Teresa John  |  1988-05-18   |       5     |   50
 Guest Guest  |  1977-11-17   |       1     |   10
 Guest Guest  |  1962-09-28   |       1     |   10
 Guest Guest  |  1977-11-17   |       1     |   10
```

**Total Customer Visit:** 20

**Total Earn:** 200

So I need the `log` to record the data by every form submission but `profile` I need to insert if the criteria of `first_name`, `last_name`, `dob` didn't match or if match, then it will update the record. If the report is for the year then the visit count and amount will added up by the first time `log` or `profile` recorded.

For the profile search, the user will only enter a name and return the value the match the search, for example the user enter `John` and the query will find from table `first_name` and `last_name` should return the following outcome:

```
Customer Name | Date of Birth | Visit Count | Row One | Row Two | Row Three
   John Doe   |  1948-12-19   |       4     |   3     |    8    |     12
   John Doe   |  2000-07-31   |       3     |   7     |    1    |     6
 Teresa John  |  1988-05-18   |       5     |   2     |    10   |     8
```

The visit count will calculate from the first day of profile created until current.

It's quite complicated, as I see it need to inter-link with each other table, but I hope there is a better way to design the `log` and `profile` table rather than crashing the whole database. **I'm not asking for do the code for me** but I'm looking for answer for a better database design to cater the desired outcome.

**Side Note:** At the moment, the application, doesn't have user login, but will implement it after I get this thing work out right. The user login only restricted to admin and user for the app purpose. The visitor or customer doesn't have the authority to login as the registeration is made in admin panel.

Hope this info will gave every member over here a clearer picture what is my intention and desired outcome.

Comment: A normalized design is usually the best way to go.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: @nescafe, I've added an answer but it may need changing/deleting depending on your clarifications: what are `dob`, `log_count` and `amount` on the `log` table used for? What are `rowone`, etc. on the `profile` table? Do users log in, or just enter their name/dob details? What exactly is "Visit Count" intended to show? hth

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, `log` is for automatically recording details of user actions, and `profile` holds the user details.

For the `log` table, you seem to be attempting to hold summarized data, that would need updating with each form submission.  I would suggest you just insert a new log entry [e.g. `log_id`, `log_date`, `profile_id`, `amount`] on submission and leave the aggregation to the report. To enable the join from `log` to `profile`, we include `profile_id`.

For the `profile` table, you should probably allow for duplicate entries of `first_name`|`last_name`|`dob` and try and find another way of making them unique (either by using `profile_id`, or by email, or passport no).

I'm not sure of your intentions for `rowone`, `rowtwo`, `rowthree`. If you know what they are, then name them explicitly; if they're for items that repeat an unknown number of times, consider moving them to a separate table (i.e. normalise).

For your report, you will then be writing a query to join the `log` and `profile` tables together, with aggregation (i.e. `GROUP BY` with `SUM` and/or `COUNT` on the necessary fields. "Visit Count" would be the `COUNT` of log entries for that profile, "Amount" would be the `SUM` of the `amount`.

Comment: I edited my first post with more information and case scenario, hopefully it can give you a clearer picture of what I intend to do so the database design will work on to cater for it.

Comment: I've updated based on your further notes. To be honest, I'm still not 100% clear. If you have a simple, unsummarised `log` table joined to the `profile` then you shouldn't have any problems "crashing the database".